# How to deal with a viewpager's FragmentStatePagerAdapter's bug on reordering fragments?

Tags: android, fragmentstatepageradapter

I think I've come across the bug of FragmentStatePagerAdapter as below:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36956111

I've tried many solutions I found on the web but they didn't work well.

Just want to ask if you guys have any solutions on that when using FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

(Returning POSITION_NONE unconditionally in getItemPosition() works, but I don't want to recreate the current and off-screen fragments unconditionally every time notifyDatasetChanged() is called)

Comment: The reason this works is because FragmentStatePagerAdapter destroys as Fragments that aren't being used. FragmentPagerAdapter does not.

Comment: I mean, those loaded fragments, including the current item and the off-screen pages, would be recreated when position_none is returned unconditionally